Inquiry About Orfi Marriage: Witness Requirements and Legal Documentation
Assalamu Alaikum wa Rahmatullahi wa Barakatuh,
I wish to marry a foreign girl through an Orfi marriage in order to avoid sin and fulfill our mutual desire to be together in a halal manner. Her parents and guardians are fully aware of and accept our marriage, and we have a mutual agreement between us, including the stipulation of a mahr.
However, I am facing some challenges and need your advice on the following points:
Witness Requirement: As I live in Egypt, I do not have many close acquaintances who can act as witnesses to our marriage. My question is, if I propose to her in a public place, such as by getting on my knees in front of a crowd, would this public declaration suffice as a witness to our marriage? Or do we still require two specific witnesses as per Islamic requirements?
Legal Documentation: Given that many lawyers are reluctant to cooperate, especially when they know it is an Orfi marriage, how crucial is the legal documentation? If we have met all the conditions of marriage—mutual consent, the presence of a wali (guardian), mahr, and witnesses (if necessary)—does the absence of an official paper affect the validity of our marriage in the eyes of Islamic law?
I am sincerely seeking to ensure that our union is halal and compliant with Islamic principles. Your guidance on these matters would be immensely valuable to us.
